# Permissions error in Docker even after giving user proper permissions

Tags: python, django, docker

If I run uWSGI as root I get an error:

```
| *** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) ***
```

and rightfully so since it is unsafe.

So I create a user and give it permissions to the relevant folders:

```
RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' django-user && \
    mkdir -p /vol/web/media && \
    mkdir -p /vol/web/static && \
    chown -R django-user:django-user /vol && \
    chmod -R 755 /vol && \
    chmod -R +x /scripts
```

However, after running I run into `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:` for files within /vol directory. Since it is flagged -R, this doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the question to share this important insight and here is the answer after trial and error. This answer is relevant for all kinds of odd docker problems:

When changing filesystem permissions prune the volumes!

```
docker [image id / system] prune -a --volumes
```

Or just delete them. I think that should work too:

```
docker volume ls
```

Then:

```
docker volume prune [volume_name]
```

I hope this helps!